# unsigned short vs unsigned int - sometimes they are the same range?

Tags: c, types, int, short

What's the difference between `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`? I found that `unsigned short` is `0-65,535` and `unsigned int` is `0-65,535` or `0-4,294,967,295`. I don't understand the difference very well. How can I know the size of data type in my architecture? And if for example `c = (unsigned short) d;` when `c` is an `unsigned short` and d is an `unsigned int` ; what is that mean? the first 16 bits from `d` are assigned to `c`?

Comment: Why are there three languages mentioned?

Comment: Sounds like C, removing extraneous language tags.

Comment: It isn't general for 3 languages?

Comment: @Lafore - No, not really. Java has a different thing.

Answer (score 6):

You're really asking what is the difference between `short` and `int`.  The answer is that `short` may be narrower, but may also be the same width as, `int`.  That's virtually all we know for sure, independent of platform.  A lot of platforms have 32-bit `int` and 16-bit `short`, but not all.

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my second part edit? :)

Comment: No, I won't, please just ask another question rather than adding on more bits to one that's already answered.  If you search for your new inquiries you will probably find they're already questions with answers on here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a useful link to explain the history of C data types:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

So the size of your data type is platform-dependent, but if your int is 32-bits in length then it will be able to represent one of 2^32 different numbers (0 - 4,294,967,295 if unsigned). Similarly if your short is 16-bits in length then it can represent one of 2^16 different numbers (0 - 65,535 if unsigned).

This link gives you the implementation details for Visual Studio 2005, where ints are 32-bits in size (4 bytes) and shorts are 16-bits (2 bytes):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx

Your exact implementation will depend on your compiler.

As for the last part of your question, yes if you attempt to cast down an int larger than the short's maximum value to a short then you will end up with a different value (probably the first 16 bits but you should test to be sure).

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my second part edit? :)

Comment: I've already seen the link. TY

Answer (score 0):

We can't say a variable type name (short, int, long, double etc.) has to point specific bit length across all microprocessor architectures or programming languages. It's mostly depended on microprocessors' architecture and of course the programming languages' definitions. Generally, signed/unsigned short should have (I would expect) half bit-size of signed/unsigned int.

Comment: No... in C `short` and `int` can very well both be 16 bits. That was the case on DOS, BTW.

Answer (score -1):

Well first you must understand what an unsigned int and short is.

Everything is broken down into bits.

A short is 16 bits, each bit being a 1 or a 0. For simplicity I will demonstrate with 4 bits

```
1000 - Unsigned = 8 
1000 - Signed = -8 
1111 - Unsigned = 15 which is equal to 2^(# of bits) -1
1111 - Signed = -1
```

Notice that with an unsigned number, the range of numbers is greater, we can make
    1111 = 15.

But with a signed number, the maximum possibility is
    0111 = 7.

Now a short has 16 bits, giving it

```
signed range of  −32,768 to 32,767  [−(2^15) to 2^15 − 1]
Unsigned range: 0 to 65,53  = 2^16 -1
```

An Int has 32 bits, giving a range of

```
Signed:−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 = −(2^31) to 2^31 − 1
Unsigned:  0 to 4,294,967,295 = 2^16 -1
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that, just an ambiguity because they have the same range of values.

Comment: @Lafore Ah. When you make a short, it doesn't guarantee 16 bits, whereas a 16bit Int does. So it's for those cases when you absolutely need a 16bit integer. Kinda odd.

Comment: Extremely wrong... a `char` is at least 8 bit, a `short` or an `int` 16, a `long` 32 bits. And on the CRAY they are _all_ 32 bits.

Comment: Huh? @vonbrand an int is 32 bits, hence why the range is 2^31-1

Comment: @BrettD The size and range of `int` is implementation-defined. The standard mandates that the range is (as for `short`) at least `-32767` to `32767`, so an `int` must be at least 16 bits wide. For `unsigned` (`int` and `short`), the range must be at least `0` to `65535`, so that too must be at least 16 bits wide. Also, the standard mandates that the range of `(unsigned) short` is contained in the range of `(unsigned) int`, and the range of `(unsigned) char` must be contained in the range of `(unsigned) short`. It is perfectly legitimate that all these types have the same width.